# Adding a dollar sign inside php

Tags: php

I'm getting data from a database and inserting it into this table.

```
while (($result_row = $result->fetch_assoc()) !== NULL) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>", $result_row['title'], "</td>";
    echo "<td>", $result_row['author'], "</td>";
    echo "<td>", $result_row['isbn'], "</td>";

    echo  "<td>", $result_row['price'], "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to print an actual $ for the price.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `echo  "<td>$", $result_row['price'], "</td>";` - It's as easy as that.

Comment: why not single quote? it will solve all the mess.

Comment: Maybe you should concretize your question. It's not clear what could be the problem with adding a single character. What have you tried? What was the error?

Comment: When you use double quotes `"` php tries to parse the content of the string. If you use single quote `'` php will understand the string as just a plain string and output it. Use `'<td>$'` instead of `"<td>$"`

Comment: Use &dollar: thats will provide you dollar sign or client page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo  "<td>$", $result_row['price'], "</td>";
```

Comment: Try using the "." period not comma, it may work a smidgen better.

Comment: `echo  "<td>$", $result_row['price'], "</td>";` worked perfectly well for me, even without escaping the dollar sign, period or comma. Both are valid. @ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: Ha - learn something new every day, it shouldn't be valid.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Don't feel bad, I actually learned that one a couple of months ago myself lol - The things we learn on Stack ;)

Comment: Thanks, so simple.  I spend about an hour trying to figure this out.  I'm still very new to php.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

```
    echo  "<td>\$", $result_row['price'], "</td>";
```

or better yet, use money_format() http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: it works with and without the \ in front of $

Comment: remember to set locale correctly before you use `money_format()`.

Comment: Try using the "." period not comma, it may work a smidgen better.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php